# Missing DataErrorInfoAdapter in latest MvvmValidation package

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm, idataerrorinfo

After updating the [MvvmValidation NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmValidation/) from version [`2.0.2`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmValidation/2.0.2) to [`3.1.0`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmValidation/3.1.0), I get the error:

> The type or namespace name **'DataErrorInfoAdapter'** could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

My `ValidatableViewModelBase.cs` looks like this:

```
public abstract class ValidatableViewModelBase : ViewModelBase, IDataErrorInfo
{
    public ValidationHelper Validator { get; } = new ValidationHelper();
    public DataErrorInfoAdapter DataErrorInfoAdapter { get; set; } // this type does not exist
    [...]

    protected ValidatableViewModelBase()
    {
        this.DataErrorInfoAdapter = new NotifyDataErrorInfoAdapter(this.Validator);
        [...]
    }

    #region IDataErrorInfo

    [Ignore]
    public string Error => this.DataErrorInfoAdapter.Error;

    [Ignore]
    public string this[string columnName] => this.DataErrorInfoAdapter[columnName];

    #endregion IDataErrorInfo
}
```

I was not able to find any migration guidelines on how to replace the deprecated `DataErrorInfoAdapter`. All I could find was [some information](https://github.com/pglazkov/MvvmValidation/issues/12#issuecomment-289224224) about the `NotifyDataErrorInfoAdapter`, but I am not quite sure if I need to change my `ValidatableViewModelBase` to implement `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface.

Do you have any advice or reference documentation for me?
Can someone explain to me, why they dropped `DataErrorInfoAdapter` but not `IDataErrorInfo`?

Comment: Did you update the actual reference in your project as well ?

Comment: @NawedNabiZada After updating the NuGet package via the NuGet package manager (which is integrated in Visual Studio), the referenced assembly was replaced with the latest one (3.1.0). I hope this answers your question. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They actually seem to have dropped the support for the `IDataErrorInfo` interface.

The new `NotifyDataErrorInfoAdapter` implements the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` that has been around since .NET Framework 4.5 was released. [Here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19490.wpf-4-5-validating-data-in-using-the-inotifydataerrorinfo-interface.aspx) is an example and more information about how to implement it.

If you want to stick to `IDataErrorInfo` for some reason, it makes no sense to upgrade `MvvmValidation` to the latest version.